# How to procure large quantities of particular wares without too much effort?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

IT is a truth universally acknowledged, that a single Paranid in possession of a good fleet must be in want of a satellite network. However, locating enough advanced satellites to place even 1 in all the ~200 sectors is a task and a half; and outfitting a fleet of ships with shields and weapons is a dozen times harder. So far I've been using the Remote Best Buy command to top-up my satellite layer, but most of the time it only manages to buy 1-3 satellites per trip. Is there a way for me to give an order to procure a number of wares and let the ship sort it out without micromanaging it every step of the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with just about every type of good in the X universe, the best and surefire way of obtaining large quantities of it is to make it yourself.  I'd recommend purchasing and setting up an [Advanced Satellite Factory](http://www.x3wiki.com/index.php/Advanced_Satellite_Factory).  And if you have the Bonus pack installed, you can keep the factory topped off with a single CLS purchasing agent.  That way you have a supply of advanced satellites whenever you want it.

As for other methods, the only other way is to find all the advanced satellite producing factories in the galaxy and making sure they're topped off and ready to produce.  And then you can park some transports at those places to snap up the supply as they come off the factory.

Finally, if you do have the PHQ, I believe you can set a never ending purchase order for advanced satellites.